# Как запустить анимацию прелоадера?

Tags: css3, анимация, css

Нужно установить прелоадер с анимированной вращающейся штукой. Взял [отсюда](http://codepen.io/mycolorpencils/pen/mcvGy) Conical Spinner, но он не вращается. Подскажите, что поправить?

```
Код HTML  
<div class="wrapper">  
    <div class="conical"></div>  
</div>

Код CSS  
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.conical{
    background-image: url('../../img/preloader.png');
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-mask: radial-gradient( circle closest-side, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0), hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) 84%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1) 86%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1) 100%) no-repeat 50% border;
    -webkit-animation: clockwise 0.75s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation: clockwise 0.75s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes clockwise
{
    to {transform: rotate(360deg) translatez(0);}
}
@keyframes clockwise
 {
     to {transform: rotate(360deg) translatez(0);}
 }

@-webkit-keyframes counter-clockwise
{
    to {transform: rotate(-360deg) translatez(0);}
}
@keyframes counter-clockwise
{
    to {transform: rotate(-360deg) translatez(0);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce
{
    50%  {transform: translatey(-20px);}
    100% {transform: translatey( 20px);}
}
@keyframes bounce
{
    50%  {transform: translatey(-20px);}
    100% {transform: translatey( 20px);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom
{
    to {
        width: calc(250px + 20px);
        margin-left: calc(-125px - 10px);
        margin-top: calc(-125px - 10px);
        border-width: 10px;
        border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoom
{
    to {
        width: calc(250px + 20px);
        margin-left: calc(-125px - 10px);
        margin-top: calc(-125px - 10px);
        border-width: 10px;
        border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes follow
{
    0% { transform: translatex(-45px); }
    100% { transform: translatex( 60px); }
}
@keyframes follow
{
    0% { transform: translatex(-45px); }
    100% { transform: translatex( 60px); }
}
```

а результат [плачевный](https://yadi.sk/d/oGFpPoUxRPNwu) - вот так вот и стоит без движения

Comment: Я вижу, что ваш код сильно отличается от их кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как минимум с примера скопирован не весь код.

Скопируй себе весь код (html, css, **js**), а потом потихоньку удаляй кусками и проверяй работоспособность.